# Drupal 7 menu limit

Tags: drupal, menu

I seem to have reached some limit with Drupal 7 Menu system.   I just added a menu item using the menu system at admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-main-menu.   I added a new entry and it is not appearing on the List Links page.   Believing there was an error, I added it 3 more times, none have displayed on the List Links page.

I examined the database table for menu_links and the table shows the presence of the 4 entries.   I have no idea if all related tables are set up correctly, or if the menu system aborted setting up all related table entries correctly, but,  menu_links definitely displays the name of the entry 4 times, and they are displayed as entries 1201, 1202, 1203, 1204.

Is 1200 the limit for creating menu links??? If there is no limit, is there some way I can recover from what is happening?   Do I need to adjust some variable to increase the number of links that can be displayed on a menu LIST LINKS page?    Currently, I have 107 entries one this one LIST LINKS page.   Other links (of the 1200) are scattered around in small menus for administration and my application.

Answer (score 0):

For those needing the information, I have identified the answer to my problem.

Drupal's  menu system allows you to create new menu links via the administrator's menu setup, but, the menu link will not display in the administrative menu list if the page has not been published.

Setting the page to published added the links to the menu list.